# Angular using interfaces with the namespace

Tags: angular, typescript, interface

I am using Angular 6 with type script 2.7.2.
I created model interfaces in separate files but with the same namespace:

**model1.ts:**

```
namespace Api {
    export interface Model1 {
       field1: string;
       field2: number;
    }
}
```

**model2.ts**

```
namespace Api {
    export interface Model2 {
       field1: string;
       field2: number;
       field3: Api.Model1;  // this caused the error
    }
}
```

Using interface Model1 into interface Model2 caused the error.

```
(TS) Namespace 'Api' has no exported member 'Model1'.
```

What is the proper way to do that ?

Comment: Can you add the error itself, otherwise it's hard to tell what might be the problem.

Comment: The error is: (TS) Namespace 'Api' has no exported member 'Model1 '. I add this to the question description.

Comment: Have you imported namespace Api in model2.ts?

Comment: No. How to do that ? Since namespace is not needed to import in component I thought it is not needed in interfaces.

Comment: Does intellisense of your editor show you 'Model1' when typing 'Api'?

Comment: No, intellisense shows only Model2, since in current file only Model2 is under the Api namespace. Other files are not recognized.

Comment: I'm deleting my answer because clearly I haven't found the problem yet.  Please add your `tsconfig.json` to the question.  Was there anything in `model1.ts` and `model2.ts` other than what is shown in the question?  If you delete all TypeScript files from the project other than those, does the problem still occur?  Can you confirm that both files are included in your build by adding a syntax error to each one and verifying that both syntax errors are reported?

Comment: I did not add import line in my question above since I thought it is not important. I have one import line in model2.ts. import { Entity } from 'breeze-client'. When I remove this import line everything works fine. How this import line can cause this kind of problem ?

Comment: Sorry, your comment didn't show up in my inbox for some reason so I only noticed it by chance now.  Adding an import turns `model2.ts` into an ES6 module, so its top-level declarations go to the module instead of the global scope.  Thus, `model2.ts` defines an `Api` namespace that shadows the global one defined in `model1.ts` instead of merging with it.  Try adding the `declare global { ... }` in `model2.ts` but not in `model1.ts` if `model1.ts` has no imports.